# Incorrect display of Russian characters in Careers

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs, github

In [my Careers profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/khartn) Russian characters display incorrectly in the data imported from Google Code and Github.

But in the data imported from LinkedIn, Russian characters display correctly.

Can you fix incorrect display of the Cyrillic symbols on importing data from Google Code and Github?

Updated:
1) OS - Win 7 RU
2) Chrome latest version on stable branch RU. I have see one moment. If I open some sites in main Chrome window than sites will shown in RU. But if I open sites in Chrome Private mode than sites will shown in English.
3) I try to import data to my resume from google code and github when I opened careers in Chrome Private mode window. May be conflicts by the chrome in private mode used EN for page requests?

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoldf.png]

Answer (score 3):

I was unable to repro this behavior.  I cloned your repos with Russian descriptions on both Github and Google Code and was able to import them both with the correct Russian text.

[image: github in russian]
[image: google code in russian]

Can you give me more detail on how you imported the projects?  It's possible I was doing something differently than you were.  It would also help to know which browser you were using.

Comment: @TartLevee is your Windows in English by default?  What steps did you take to repro it?  Please edit the question and add any info you can at the bottom.

Comment: Sorry, @Nick. I mean I can repro in that I can see question marks where there should be Cyrillic characters in the OP's resume. I didn't try to do an import of the data.

Comment: @TartLevee aye, we can see the data in there as all question marks, even in the db, so something happened before that point.  We just need more explanation from Arthur to help us find it.

Comment: I have updated my question